# Pagerduty API returns data on Postman but empty on Node

Tags: node.js, pagerduty

I can't understand this after a lot of head-scratching. What am I missing?

Pagerduty returns data when doing a call on Postman (in this example returns 2 objects)

[image]

But when doing the same call on a NodeJs app, it returns no data and with reseted created_at_start and created_at_end values

```
$ node gen.js -r incident --serviceId=PM7EKHT
Fetching incident...
Incident Data:
{
  aggregate_unit: null,
  data: [],
  filters: {
    created_at_end: '2023-09-14T17:32:38.170522Z',
    created_at_start: '2023-09-13T17:32:38.170482Z'
  },
  order: 'desc',
  order_by: 'total_incident_count',
  time_zone: 'Etc/UTC'
}
```

My JS code is this:

```
async function fetchIncidentsByService(serviceId) {
    try {
        const loadingInterval = loadingAnimation('Fetching incident...');
        const postData = {
            filters: {
              created_at_start: "2023-08-01T00:00:00-05:00",
              created_at_end: "2023-08-31T00:00:00-05:00",
              service_ids: [ serviceId ]
            },
            aggregate_unit: "week",
            time_zone: "Etc/UTC"
        }

        const response = await makeRequest(apiKey, '/analytics/metrics/incidents/services', 'POST', postData);

        clearInterval(loadingInterval);

        console.log('\nIncident Data:');
        console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

With the makeRequest function on a separate module:

```
const https = require('https');

async function makeRequest(apiKey, path, method = 'GET', postData = null) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const options = {
        hostname: 'api.pagerduty.com',
        path: path,
        method: method,
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Token token=${apiKey}`,
          'Accept': 'application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2',
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          'X-EARLY-ACCESS': 'analytics-v2'
        },
      };

      if (method === 'POST' && postData !== null ) {
        options.body = JSON.stringify(postData);
      }

      const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        let data = '';
  
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
          data += chunk;
        });
  
        res.on('end', () => {
          if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300) {
            resolve(JSON.parse(data));
          } else {
            reject(new Error(`Request failed with status code ${res.statusCode}`));
          }
        });
      });
  
      req.on('error', (error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
  
      req.end();
    });
  }

module.exports = { makeRequest };
```